# How to set different style for each column from configuration

Tags: python, pandas

This is my configuration :

```py
"columns": [
    {
        "field": "field1",
        "style": "'color:red' if val > 0 else 'color:green'"
    },
    {
        "field": "field2",
        "style": "'color:red' if val < 0 else 'color:green'"
    }
]
```

and this is my code that apply the style:

```py
for column in columns:
    if "style" in column:
        tab_df = tab_df.style.applymap(
            lambda val: eval(column.get("style")), subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, [column.get("field")]]
        )
```

it is work only for first style, but for the second i got :

```py
AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'style'"
```

So, there is another way to do it correctly?

Comment: can you post your tab_df too?

Comment: @Pygirl it is just pandas data frame...

Comment: can you just post tab_df.head() ?? It would be easier to provide a solution.

Comment: @Pygirl pd.DataFrame([{"field1": 1, "field2": 1}])

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function where you pass the list of color, depending on fields:

```
def highlight(x,val=0,colors={}):
    if x.name in colors:
        c0,c1 = colors[x.name]
        return np.where(x>val, f'color:{c1}', f'color:{c0}')
    else:
        return [''] * len(x)

# Apply style
df.style.apply(highlight, colors={'field1':['green','red'],
                                  'field2':{'red','green'}}
              )
```

Output:

[image]